# DNS failing to resolve but nslookup succeeds

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Getting confusing results from a domain+zone both in AWS.

My domain has four nameservers:

```
ns-604.awsdns-11.net
ns-493.awsdns-61.com
ns-1032.awsdns-01.org
ns-1574.awsdns-04.co.uk
```

I have the following hosted zone and record (in addition to the standard NS and SOA records):

```
example.com.   A     192.0.2.4
```

If I run `dig example.com +noall +answer` I receive an empty response instead of the expected `example.com   1    IN     192.0.2.4`

However, if I perform these `nslookup` I receive the expected responses:

```
nslookup example.com ns-604.awsdns-11.net
nslookup example.com ns-493.awsdns-61.com
nslookup example.com ns-1032.awsdns-01.org
nslookup example.com ns-1574.awsdns-04.co.uk

Server:         ns-1574.awsdns-04.co.uk
Address:        205.251.198.38#53

Name:   example.com
Address: 192.0.2.4
```

I also receive a `2(SERVFAIL)` from `host`

```
host example.com
Host example.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)
```

Not sure what's going on here.  `nslookup` shows that my DNS is pointed to the right IP, but `host` and `dig` both fail.

Comment: what if you run `host mydomain.com 8.8.8.8`? or `dig mydomain.com @8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @Andrew I get `Host mydomain.com not found: 2(SERVFAIL)` and an empty answer section, respectively.

Comment: Did you set your nameservers at your domain registrar? Not doing so is the usual cause of this problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton AWS/Route53 is also the registrar, and the nameservers on the domain are identical to the namservers in the hosted zone's NS record.

Comment: Did you only just purchase the domain, then?

Comment: @MichaelHampton no I've owned the domain for a while, it was just unused.  I created my hosted zone, then update the domain's nameservers to match the ones in the hosted zone's NS record.

Comment: 1) give the true name involved without useless obfuscation (I fixed your values per RFC2606 and 5737) if you want quick and useful help 2) use `dig`, it is a superior tool to `nslookup` and `host` 3) always use dig with the `@` option to specify which nameserver you query 4) quick troubleshooting scenario: first check the authoritative nameservers then the recursive one. Also use online tools: https://zonemaster.net/ and https://dnsviz.net/ . If the authoritative have the data but not the recursive ones it is just a rejuvenation issue, so wait... (or a lame delegation)

Comment: @PatrickMevzek https://zonemaster.net/test/25323900ede06c1b shows the only warning as `All nameservers in the delegation have IPv6 addresses in the same AS (16509).` . Could you expand on how to check if the authoritative have the data but not the recursive ones?  The only thing I found reading through the output was `None of the following nameservers is a recursor : ns-1052.awsdns-03.org/205.251.196.28, ns-1569.awsdns-04.co.uk/205.251.198.33, ns-319.awsdns-39.com/205.251.193.63, ns-753.awsdns-30.net/205.251.194.241.`

Comment: Notice that none of the nameservers in that response are the ones you are using nsloolup against, @diplosaurus.  Your domain's authoritative servers list points to different nameservers, and therefore a different hosted zone... probably one that you deleted at some point in the past.

Comment: The solution will be the same as the one in [Deleted then recreated Route 53 hosted zones, now website not working](https://serverfault.com/a/838396/153161).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Zonemaster test you have done (https://zonemaster.net/test/25323900ede06c1b) shows your domain, we would have been able to reply sooner with more helpful information if you did give it right at the start.

Anyway, the test is ok which means there is no lame delegation, the set of NS records in your parent zone and in your own zone match.

Indeed they are:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
nickbrown.me.       60  IN  NS  ns-1052.awsdns-03.org.
nickbrown.me.       60  IN  NS  ns-1569.awsdns-04.co.uk.
nickbrown.me.       60  IN  NS  ns-319.awsdns-39.com.
nickbrown.me.       60  IN  NS  ns-753.awsdns-30.net.
```

Note that these are **NOT** the ones you give in your question.

If you query any of them, for an A record at the apex they all reply with `35.162.177.171` so this is consistent and working.
Your zone is correctly installed and works.

Now if we try some "well known" open recursive resolvers: both Google (`8.8.8.8`), Quad9 (`9.9.9.9`) and Cloudflare (`1.1.1.1`) reply with the same answer.

So in short everything works, except that from your question you do not test the correct authoritative nameservers, and you do not specify exactly which recursive ones you use so they may have problems or have specific configurations for your zone.

Since `whois` shows your domain had an update recently (`2018-04-04T21:43:23Z`) you may have changed something and not tested things correctly at the correct time.